# JDK interface for processing a generic parameter

Tags: generics, interface, java, java-7

Is there an interface from the JDK that looks something like this:

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    public void process(T t);
}
```

The requirement is to implement a callback that *runs* code, but doesn't return anything.

I could write my own (by simply using the example code here), but I'd like to use an existing wheel if one exists, rather that reinventing one.

Comment: This can be easily interpreted as looking for Java Annotation Processing API because: Annotation Processing API is a **callback** mechanism and is meant to **process** generic annotations. But turns out such interpretation is wrong. I'd suggest that this question is either trivial or misleading.

Comment: @edwardw I have shuffled the question text around to make what I *thought* was already clear, more clear.

Comment: That's the easiest wheel to reinvent ever.

Comment: @edwardw How is it misleading? (And how do annotations enter in to it?)

Comment: @Dave Newton three things in the question: callback + generic + process. Besides, as you said, I certainly didn't anticipate such an easy question. So I thought inquirer was not aware of annotation processing API and was looking for it. Of course it could be just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8, [the `java.util.function.Consumer` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) does exactly what you want.

It has one non-default method, which accepts a generic type and returns nothing:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {

    void accept(T t);

    default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

So you need something like

```
interface Foo<T>
    bar(T)
```

Only 3 interfaces in JDK are like that

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryStream$Filter<T>

    boolean accept(T entry) throws IOException;


java.lang.Comparable<T>

    int compareTo(T o);


javax.xml.ws.Provider<T>

    T invoke(T request);
```

Obviously you won't like them.

Async IO has a callback interface, but it's a bit more complicated:

```
java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler<V,A>

    void completed(V result, A attachment);

    void failed(Throwable exc, A attachment);
```

Comment: So how do you know there are only 3 interface like that?  If you parse javadocs I will +1 you, otherwise I don't think you could *know* that for sure.

Comment: by reflection on all java/javax classes

Comment: that's left as an exercise for the reader:) basically, for all jre jars, list entries to get all classes, then reflect on each class.

Comment: It's a well-researched answer, but you're right - they aren't a good fit. Thanks though (+1)

Comment: @MK. Not much code to post for that, really. Plus there are libraries that'll do signature searching for you, for even less code.

Comment: Well, it seems the answer actually is "there isn't such an interface", making this answer the "most correct", especially considering the `void` return type requirement

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't believe there's such an interface currently. There's currently slated to be such an interface, called `Block` (with an `apply` method, I think), in JDK 8... though the name could well change between now and then.

Comment: and the funny thing is, in java8, caller can use lambda expression without mentioning the interface/method; so it's not a big deal for Bohemian to introduce his own interface.

Comment: It is an `apply` method at this time of writing. See [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/085fb9c9164f/src/share/classes/java/util/functions/Block.java).

Comment: @saintali: `java.util.functions.Block`, currently anyway.

Comment: I ended up reading all classes in `java.util.functions`. Really fun! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like Guava's [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html), except a Function is allowed returning something. It thus looks like a

```
public interface Callback<T> extends Function<T, Void> {
}
```

Not part of the JDK, but Guava is so commonly used now that you might find it handy.

Answer (score 2):

The real question here is why?  Why do you think that defining your interface for this is worse than using one provided by Java?  What are you going to gain?  You will lose the ability to pick an appropriate name.  I think that's about it.  If there was a reason for you to use an existing interface provided by Java libraries you would *already know* its name because you would know which part of the library you are planning to interface with.
Creating an interface with one method is not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Two reasons: a) I want to avoid class bloat and b) one should use what's there if it fits

Comment: If I read your code and see you using a Java library interface I will incorrectly assume that it is in fact being used to interface with that library.

Comment: So if I implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, that means I'm "interfacing with java.lang library"? ...No, it doesn't, does it. You've seriously missed the point of the question. I want something as general as `Comparable` but with a signature as per the question. (Actually, Comparable is the closest fit - see irreputable's answer)

Comment: Well, if you plan to use Comparable for what you are describing I don't even.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, there's no such interface readily available in the JDK. Generics only came in late to the Java game. Before that, there was the need to pass around several typed arguments to a callback in a semi-type safe way and without prior knowledge of those arguments structure (I say "semi-type safe" because event listeners were invented to test the event's type and cast as needed). You could not have built that mechanism without generics and they never did re-architect the whole JDK to have generics in mind (except the collections API and a few others). It would have been a massive undertaking with little gains (after all, everything *was* working as expected).

Hence, the observer/listener pattern that is pervasive on JDK libraries (see `java.util.EventObject`, `java.util.EventListerner` and their usages). Java also believes in being a little more verbose during interface definition, when implementing `EventListener`. For clearer implementations, specialized implementations of that pattern should make the callback method name demonstrate the purpose of the code (which usually also matches the event's name). E.g., `ActionEvent#actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

Another possible for reason for that interface to be absent is that it is not used in the JDK itself. Sometimes you wish for `Callback<T>` others for `Callback<T, V>` or even `Callback<T, R, V>`, etc. Providing those interfaces without any real is use case (inside the JDK) is really not a very design policy. That lack of support for such useful constructs is the main reason why Guava and Apache Commons (among others) exist.

Anyway, I agree with @JB Nizet that you should be using Guava. We didn't specify why and how you are using the interface, so that leaves a lot of room to speculation, but whatever reason, Guava will probably have other functionality that might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to apply the Observer design pattern, Java supports it in its standard library since JDK 1.0. The interface you are looking for is java.util.Observer. The other side of the pattern is the java.util.Observable class. Basically, you extend java.util.Observable, and then register your Observers (as far as I can understand, an Observer can observe more than one Observable at the same time). It's quite ancient stuff, so beware: no generics.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**, because `Observable` is not typed and the question clearly requires a *typed* class/interface. However, given your low reputation, I won't downvote you - I will allow you to delete this post instead

Comment: No, you did not clearly request a _generic_ (rather than _typed_) class/interface. You asked for something looking "_like_ this", which is misleading on what you are and you are not willing to trade against compatibility with standard libraries.

Comment: In java, "typed" means "has a generic parameter". And if you read the question, especially the title, it clearly asks for a **generic** class (the word "typed" does not appear anywhere in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I've used Callable ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to implement callbacks/functors in java.

```
interface Callable<V> {
    public V call();
}
```

You can process this using the Executors stuff in java.util.concurrent.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**, because the `call` method does not *accept* type `V`, but rather *returns* it. However, given your low reputation, I won't downvote you - I will allow you to delete this post instead.

Comment: I think this is, nevertheless, helpful. +1

Comment: @jayunit100 How is it helpful? Exactly how does the `call()` method get access to the object?

Comment: Guess I misunderstood the question.  I know this isn't the exact signature, however it is a way to implement a callback.  The callback object itself implements callable; the logic of the actual callback goes in the implementation of the call method.  Doing it this way makes your callback implementations compatible with the scheduling and execution code in Java.until.concurrent.Executor, etc.  However if your approach requires exactly the interface above, then as others have said, you'll most likely need to roll your own.  If this still makes no sense to you I'll delete.

Comment: @Bohemian Kind of harsh on DietCoke aren't ya?  Geez.

Comment: @JoshuaDavis Well, the answer is totally off-topic and therefore *not* helpful. But yeah - I should have eased back on the scolding and left it polite and professional. Not an excuse, but maybe a reason: I have a 9-month old and haven't had a solid night's sleep since she was born. Maybe I'm prone to be cranky due to lack of sleep :/

Comment: @DietCokeOfEvil You *can't* implement a callback pattern using `Callable`, because there is no parameter being passed to the `call()` method! The whole idea is that the object you pass in will be given back to you for further processing - that's why it's called "callback"... you are "called back"

Comment: @Bohemian Cranky software engineers?  Why I never!  ;->  Anyway, I agree with JB Niznet - Function from Guava is the closest thing, IMO.

Comment: You don't need to pass parameters to call() - you implement callable and pass the parameters into the subclass's constructor.  Effectively this is the functor pattern in which an object contains the data and behaviour that represents a function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is called annotation processing. [JSR 269: Pluggable Annotation Processing API](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269) defines the API and it is part of JDK 6. You can start from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#processing) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html).

Comment: Eh? You probably need to provide a little more information in order for this answer to be helpful.

Comment: @edwardw What on earth has annotation processing got to do with this question? By any chance did you submit your answer the wrong question?

Comment: @Bohemian oh, then I misread your question. So you already answered your own question. Why bother in the first place?

Comment: Let me elaborate. Annotation Processing API is a **callback** mechanism. And, it is meant to **process** generic annotations. Fit the bill, right? If so, I'd consider your question either trivial or misleading.

Comment: @edwardw If you find an `interface` (or abstract class) that matches the requirements of my question, post it here and I'll accept your answer! (Telling me about a framework that *uses* callbacks doesn't actually answer my question)